# Creating a summary from two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

I have two tables and I'm trying to create a summary with the sum of amount due per person but don't have the creative ID involved.

```
Table 1:
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Lname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `state` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `zip` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `business_name varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,

Second table:
`id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `C_ID` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `Amount_Due` DECIMAL(7 , 2 ) not null DEFAULT 0,
    `created_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `closed_date` DATETIME default NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)  ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=LATIN1;
```

Here is what I'm trying to do:

- I'm trying to make a summary with dates within 5/1/18 and 6/15/18.
- Have the sum of due amount for each person
- Have these aliases : Business name, Phone Number ,Invoiced Amounts

I'm trying to test my code but i'm getting errors:

```
SELECT Name,phone,SUM(Amount_Due) FROM test_customer,test_invoices 
WHERE created_date BETWEEN '2018-05-01' AND  "2018-06-15'
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result? that really help

Comment: What's your error?

Comment: ER_PARSE_ERROR which is what i'm getting

Comment: INSERT INTO `test_customer` (`fname`,`lname`,`phone1`,`address1`,`city`,`state`,`zip`,`email`,`business_name`)
VALUES ('Jimmy','Paulk','4785555215','123 Main','Ober','PA','15214','jp@stdvlv.com','Standard Valve');
INSERT INTO `test_invoices` (`customer_id`,`due_amount`,`paid_amount`,`created_date`,`closed_date`) VALUES (5,510.18,145,'2018-07-03','2018-07-18');

Comment: What's your expect result from your sample data?

Comment: Customer Name,Phone number, Amount due

Comment: I answer your question but your where condition will not match any data, because there isn't a date from  '2018-05-01'  to "2018-06-15' in `created_date ` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to use `JOIN` instead of `,`(`CROSS JOIN`) and `GROUP BY` in non-aggregate function columns.

```
SELECT Name 'Customer Name',
      phone 'Phone number',
      SUM(i.Amount_Due) 'Amount due'
FROM test_customer c 
INNER JOIN test_invoices i ON C.id = i.C_ID
GROUP BY Name,phone
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bc6738/11)

Comment: I'm getting this:  Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'i.Amount_Due' in 'field list'

Comment: Are you sure `Amount_Due` exists in your `test_invoices` table? or you can see my sqlfiddle I use your sample data it is worked

Comment: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'C.id' in 'on clause'

Comment: Could you give me some picture from your table schema and datas? Because I guess your sample data can't match with your current data.